# Como fazer Tag não sofrer um atributo da Tag cujo esta alojada?

Tags: div, img

Como eu faço para tirar uma tag de outra? 
Ex.:

```
<div>
    <img src="...">
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <a href="...">...</a>
</div>
```

No caso, eu quero colocar um atributo no `<div>` para fazer um quadrado com uma cor, mas quero que a imagem fique a esquerda do quadrado e não dentro.O que eu faço?

Comment: se é pra imagem estar fora da div e à esquerda, por que enão coloca ela fora da div então? pode colocar ambas dentro de outra div e usar `display` para posicionar como quiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você têm que usar a propriedade `position: absolute` na div/elemento que você quer deixar em outro lugar e definir a quanto do top/bottom/left/right o elemento vai estar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: red; margin-left: 50%; text-align: center; width: 500px; height: 200px">
                Q1
                <div style="position: absolute; right: 50%; text-align: center; top: 8px; background-color: blue; width: 500px; height: 200px;">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mac.jpg" width="500px" height="200px"/>
                </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: e onde está a solução para imagem? sua resposta não demonstra como resolver o problema

Comment: editei @RicardoPontual